# Printing precise error messages in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, subprocess

Is there a way to get more specific Error messages in Python?  E.g The full error code or at least the line the error occurred on, the exact file that cannot be found rather than a generic `"The system cannot find the file specified")`

```
for file in ['C:/AA/HA.csv', 'C:/AA1/HA1.csv']:
        try:
            os.remove(file)
        except OSError as e:
            pass
            print(getattr(e, 'message', repr(e)))
            #print(getattr(e, 'message', repr(e)))
            #print(e.message)
            #print('File Not Removed')
```

The following prints twice:

```
FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified')
```

While this is great, is there a way to get more precise error messages for bug fixing?

The following stops the job but gives out in console the `exact line being 855` as well as the file `directory ''C:/AC/HA.csv''.`

```
os.remove('C:/AA/HA.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ACA.py", line 855, in <module>
    os.remove('C:/AC/HA.csv')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: ''C:/AC/HA.csv''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/traceback.html#module-traceback) module:

```
import os
import traceback

for file in ['C:/AA/HA.csv', 'C:/AA1/HA1.csv']:
    try:
        os.remove(file)
    except OSError as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.remove(file)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/AA/HA.csv'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.remove(file)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:/AA1/HA1.csv'
```